# Clear basket after 12h? laravel task

Tags: laravel

Little question about laravel and the Task Scheduling,
My basket is not made by session, i made this choice because i wanted to update the product quantity's value with all baskets for an egality between the customers. Was thinking to maybe delete all unvalided baskets after 12h.

Can I try this way ?

Comment: Sure you can, [see here](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/queues#creating-jobs)... good luck

Comment: Like @zanderwar said, create a job and schedule it with something like `$schedule->job(new Heartbeat)->everyFiveMinutes();`

see https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/scheduling

Comment: yeah i've seen that i just wanted an advice to be sur that it was the best way :) (maybe the better way was to not use basket to update the product quantity's.) thank you guys